# I have to open and call intent Digital Wellbeing & Parental Controls

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to open and call Android phone intent, Digital Wellbeing & Parental Controls.

I tried to use:
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DIGITAL_WELLBEING_SETTINGS);

and it's not correct.

How can I call to WELLBEING or "Focus mode" intent.
In addition just I have to open intent like startActivity(intent);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's a little bit professional question to who have experience about this problem can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Pixel, you can use this code

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.wellbeing", "com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.settings.TopLevelSettingsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```